# Setting trust level to High in Web.config makes application run slower?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Can anybody shed any light on the following behavior.  We had a UAT and Production version of a .NET web application. UAT was taking around 5 seconds to run a particular operation while Prod was taking 35+ seconds.

This even happened when pointing both web applications at the same database and putting them both on the same machine.

The culprit was finally found to be the following entry, which was in the Prod but not UAT web.config

```
<trust level="High" originUrl="" />
```

Can anybody shed any light on why this would cause such a significant performance degradation??

Comment: May I suggest profiling?

Comment: Nice question. Purely out of curiosity did putting that in the UAT web.config reproduce the problem ?

Comment: Yes I can consistently remove and add that line to web.config in UAT and this particular query on the UAT site takes 5 seconds without it and ~40 seconds with it.

Comment: @Domenic: Profiling would be good, but I currently don't have tools on the server in question and was wondering if anyone had an explanation off the top of their head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code Access Security checks do add a cost which is largely optimized out in full trust mode so it is at least conceivable that this is the culprit. Assuming you can repro the same effect on your workstation, definitely profile it.